# Expo could not find/run adb.exe file from Android Studio

Tags: javascript, linux, android-studio, expo

I am trying to set up my pc to develop apps using Expo and Android Studio. I already have both installed and running, but when I try running "npx expo start", and selecting in Metro Bundler to open in Android adb.exe, i keep getting this error:

Error: spawn /mnt/c/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb ENOENT

Keep in mind I am using WSL, but the AndroidStudio is located in Windows.

I have already typed and updated the .bashrc file with:
"export ANDROID_SDK=:/mnt/c/Users/Usuario/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools" in the to set the correct path, but it still isn't working. I'm able to locate and execute the adb.exe file by my own using the terminal and in the same path.
Any tips?